# SAS What if Analysis data interval with gaps

Tags: sas

I have a question about SAS what if statement. Say that we have the following program:

```
data work.stress;
infile tests;
input ID Name $ Tolerance;
if tolerance <= 5 then tolerance = "Low";
else if tolerance >= 6 then tolerance = "High";
run;
```

I know we should always make sure data intervals has no gap between them, but just say this IS the program we are running, what if there's a observation that has a tolerance as 5.5? Will the output show a Syntax error?

Thanks!

JessX

Answer (score 0):

When using `if-then-else` there is no syntax error caused by failing to fit in any particular if/else statement; it just doesn't do anything.  So in your case, `tolerance` would have its original value if it had value 5.5.  This would be commonly done in cases where you want to censor extreme values, though you'd use a special missing usually (assuming you want these extreme values excluded from the analysis):

```
data work.stress;
  infile tests;
  input ID Name $ Tolerance;
  if tolerance <= 5 then tolerance = .L;
  else if tolerance >= 6 then tolerance = .H;
run;
```

(In fact, it will have missing values for the "High" "Low" groups as you wrote it, since you defined it as a numeric value.)

If you use `select-when`, then you do have to account for every single possible value - if you don't have an `otherwise`, it will fail on any value not covered by a `when`.  This is part of why it's helpful to use `select-when`.

Answer (score 0):

An error there will be, but not for the reason you mention. If you try replacing a number by a string, SAS will not allow it.

Two possible avenues:

1. Declare a format using `proc format` where you specify your thresholds. Values falling between the cracks of your thresholds will just be displayed as they are (numeric).
2. Create a new variable.

In this example, whatever falls between 5 and 6 will have a missing value for the new `tolerance` variable, unless you add a "MID" category:

```
data work.stress;
  infile tests(rename=(Tolerance=Tol_num));
  input ID Name $ Tolerance;
  format tolerance $8.;
  if tol_num = . then tolerance = "?";
  else if tol_num <= 5 then tolerance = "LOW";
  else if tol_num >= 6 then tolerance = "HIGH";
  else tolerance = "MID";
  drop tol_num;
run;
```